# C error: .o File format not recognized

Tags: c, netbeans, format

I have a C project with three C files and a .h file. I work in NetBeans. When I try to make an import I get this error:

```
gcc     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/progetto build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/initialization.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/utility.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/model_parameters.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/condensation.o -L/usr/local/lib -lm I have to-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lXm -lXt -lXext -lX11 -lz -lpthread -lcurses -ldl 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/model_parameters.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to remove this import but the error doesn't disappear. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Well, what kind of file is `build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/model_parameters.o`?

Comment: I not have create .o file, I create model_parameters.c, NetBeans create this file

Comment: So you are using gcc to link object files (created by NetBeans) using the above?? You have not compiled your .c files yourself with gcc ???

Comment: Is this a true copy of what you have entered to build this ??

Comment: What result do you get from: `file build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/model_parameters.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/initialization.o`?  If, as I expect, the results are different, you'll need to remove `parameters.o` and rebuild it with the correct compilation options.